# How can i connect to multiple hosts in Marklogic Data Movement SDK?

Tags: marklogic, java

I want to run the Marklogic Data Movement SDK for a transform module , in distributed mode on my Marklogic cluster which is running on 3Nodes. Usually in the mlcp we will use the `-host` parameter to specify our hostnames and have `-mode` parameter to define our mode type. Is it possible here in DMSDK to mention all the hostnames of our nodes in ML cluster like this

```
DatabaseClient client = DatabaseClientFactory.newClient ("host1,host2,host3", port, "x", "x", DatabaseClientFactory.Authentication.DIGEST);
```

So that it will distribute the task efficiently. But i didnt seen any documentation of DMSDK with multiple hosts.

1. If i am not giving my all the hostnames then how it gonna distribute the work in parallel fashion.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MarkLogic is a clustered solution. It is well aware of the nodes in its cluster. The data movement SDK is cluster-aware and is smart enough to know what hosts are in the cluster and can write to them just by you providing one hostname.

As an example, you need only scroll down on the mian page:  https://developer.marklogic.com/learn/data-movement-sdk

The section on WriteBatcher describes the round-robin method it uses.

And for what it is worth, MLCP had the same abilties - or could even write to the same server for which a document's forest was available.

This is the best I can do to answer for you since there is not really a clean question.  Please start with the link above and post a more detailed question if you still get stuck.